# how to center a <div> horizontally in css?

Tags: html, css

How can I center this 3 divs in my footer with CSS? 
I first search here in stackoverflow and I tried `margin: 0 auto`, `text-align: center; display: inline-block;` and nothing works, so How can I center this 3 divs in the footer?

I can't use flex.

```css
/* ------- Footer ------*/
.footer-box{
    margin: 20px;
}
.footer-box > h1{
        color:#000000;
        font-size: 30pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.footer-box > p{
        color:#303030;
        font-size: 18pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer-social-box{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-social{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:32px;
    height: 32px;
    border:2px solid #606060;
    margin-right: 15px;

}

.img-twitter{
    background: url(../img/twitter.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.img-facebook{
    background: url(../img/facebook.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.img-instagram{
    background: url(../img/instagram.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-box">
            <h1>SOCIAL</h1>
            <p>Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo.</p>
            <div class="footer-social-box">
                <div><a class="footer-social img-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
                <div><a class="footer-social img-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
                <div><a class="footer-social img-instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

https://jsbin.com/yaficokodu/edit?html,css,output

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is all you need:

```
.footer-social-box > div {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

The div wrappers of your anchor elements (`.footer-social`) are block-level elements. That means they are occupying 100% width of their parent (`.footer-social-box`).

When a box consumes the full width of its container it obviously can't be centered because there's no free space.

In your code below, the `div` children of `.footer-social-box` need to be `inline-block`.

```
<div class="footer-social-box">
    <div><a class="footer-social img-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
    <div><a class="footer-social img-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
    <div><a class="footer-social img-instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
 </div>
```

Comment: Thank you, there is the big explanation I want to hear.

Answer (score 1):

Simply give those divs a class and set them to `display:inline-block;` Here is your demo of a fiddle showing that. https://jsfiddle.net/mkf5k3Lt/1/

Comment: Totally works!!!
Can you explain to me why I just can set `display:inline-block;` in the .footer-social class? just because is not a div?

Comment: Sure. `<div>` elements are considered block level elements by default. The reason i set a class to those three divs was because I only wanted to target those three divs not the rest of your divs throughout your document. I then told them to `display:inline-block;` instead of block which allows those divs to have width and height to them. inline-block elements are like inline elements except they allow your divs to have width and height which allowed me to center them in the `.footer-box` div class. Hope that was clear enough.

Comment: Really Clear, that's help me a lot.
Now I see clearly the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.footer-social-box div{
display:inline-block;
margin:0 auto;
width:32px;
height: 32px;
margin-right: 15px;
}
```

What this does is target the divs inside *footer-social-box* class, centers it, gives it a width, height and margin.

Complete code is below:

```css
 /* ------- Footer ------*/
.footer-box{
    margin: 20px;
}
.footer-box > h1{
        color:#000000;
        font-size: 30pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.footer-box > p{
        color:#303030;
        font-size: 18pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer-social-box{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
 
 
.footer-social-box div{
    display:inline-block;
 margin:0 auto;
 width:32px;
    height: 32px;
 margin-right: 15px;
  border:1px solid #000000; /* placed only to see where divs are, can be removed */
}
 
 
.footer-social{
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
    width:32px;
    height: 32px;
    border:2px solid #606060;
    margin-right: 15px;

}

.img-twitter{
    background: url(../img/twitter.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.img-facebook{
    background: url(../img/facebook.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.img-instagram{
    background: url(../img/instagram.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
```

```html
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-box">
            <h1>SOCIAL</h1>
            <p>Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo.</p>
            <div class="footer-social-box">
                <div><a class="footer-social img-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
                <div><a class="footer-social img-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
                <div><a class="footer-social img-instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
```

Let me know how this goes.

Cheers

Comment: That's an awesome solution also more responsive.

Comment: Am glad you like it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Better If you use un ordered list style. Take a look on that.

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato);
@import url(https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.css);
body {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
    color: #FFF;
    background: #322f30;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
}
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
}
p > a:hover{
    color: #d9d9d9;
    text-decoration:  underline;
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
    margin:  1% 0 1% 0;
}
._12 {
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
._14 {
    font-size: 1.4em;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    list-style: none;
}
.footer-social-icons {
    width: 350px;
    display:block;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
.social-icon {
    color: #fff;
}
ul.social-icons {
    margin-top: 10px;
}
.social-icons li {
    vertical-align: top;
    display: inline;
    height: 100px;
}
.social-icons a {
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.fa-facebook {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
.fa-facebook:hover {
    background-color: #3d5b99;
}
.fa-twitter {
    padding:10px 12px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
.fa-twitter:hover {
    background-color: #00aced;
}
.fa-rss {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
.fa-rss:hover {
    background-color: #eb8231;
}
.fa-youtube {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
.fa-youtube:hover {
    background-color: #e64a41;
}
.fa-linkedin {
    padding:10px 14px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
.fa-linkedin:hover {
    background-color: #0073a4;
}
.fa-google-plus {
    padding:10px 9px;
    -o-transition:.5s;
    -ms-transition:.5s;
    -moz-transition:.5s;
    -webkit-transition:.5s;
    transition: .5s;
    background-color: #322f30;
}
.fa-google-plus:hover {
    background-color: #e25714;
}
```

```html
<div class="footer-social-icons">
    <h4 class="_14">Follow us on</h4>
    <ul class="social-icons">
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-rss"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-linkedin"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="" class="social-icon"> <i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Click [here](https://codepen.io/Deadlymuffin/pen/hGiqo/"Example")!

Answer (score 0):

Check this code

```
  /* ------- Footer ------*/
  .footer-box > h1{
    color:#000000;
    font-size: 30pt;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
  }
  .footer-box > p{
    color:#303030;
    font-size: 18pt;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 50px;
  }


  .footer-social-box{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
  }
  .footer-social-box > div{
    background: red; /*remove*/
    margin: auto;
    display: inline-block;
  }
  .footer-social{
    /*display: inline-block;*/
    float:left;
    width:32px;
    height: 32px;
    border:2px solid #606060;
    margin-right: 15px;
  }

  .img-twitter{
    background: url(../img/twitter.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
  .img-facebook{
    background: url(../img/facebook.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
  .img-instagram{
    background: url(../img/instagram.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
  }
```

Regard

Answer (score 0):

The social icon were floated making the div container look kinda empty. See below

```css
* ------- Footer ------*/
.footer-box{
    margin: 20px;
}
.footer-box > h1{
        color:#000000;
        font-size: 30pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 35px;
}

.footer-box > p{
        color:#303030;
        font-size: 18pt;
        text-align: center;
        margin-bottom: 50px;
}
.footer-social-box{
    width: 100%;
    line-height: 32px;
    text-align: center;
}
.footer-social-box > div{
    display: inline-block;
}
.footer-social{
    display: block;
    width:32px;
    height: 32px;
    border:2px solid #606060;
    margin-right: 15px;

}
.footer-social {
    text-align: center;

}

.img-twitter{
    background: url(../img/twitter.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.img-facebook{
    background: url(../img/facebook.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
.img-instagram{
    background: url(../img/instagram.png) no-repeat center center scroll;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
    <footer>
        <div class="footer-box">
            <h1>SOCIAL</h1>
            <p>Quisque lorem tortor fringilla sed, vestibulum id, eleifend justo.</p>
            <div class="footer-social-box">
                <div><a class="footer-social img-twitter" href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
                <div><a class="footer-social img-facebook" href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
                <div><a class="footer-social img-instagram" href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"></a></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```